# Why do dictioniaries have .updateValue()?

Tags: swift

Let's say we have a dictioniary:

```
var myDict = [1: "firstValue", 2: "secondValue"]
```

It seems to me that, when wanting to change the value with key 1

```
myDict.updateValue("diffFirstValue", forKey: 1)
```

has the exact same function as

```
myDict[1] = "diffFirstValue"
```

**Then why does .updateValue() exist for dictionaries?**

Comment: these are language features for flexibility.

Comment: And if you read the docs, you might notice that the functionality of `updateValue` and `myDict[key] = ...` is not the same. The subscript operator is a combination of `updateValue(forKey:)` and `removeValue(forKey:)`. If you had a dictionary with values of an optional type (I don't advise to use such dictionaries), you would have noticed the difference very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/1539001-updatevalue), it returns the value that was replaced or nil if a new value was added:

> Use this method instead of key-based subscripting when you need to know whether the new value supplants the value of an existing key

**Replacing a value**

```
var dictionary = ["A": 1, "B": 2]

if let oldValue = dictionary.updateValue(100, forKey: "A") {
    print("Old value: \(oldValue)")
} else {
    print("New value added")
}
```

It prints: "*Old value: 1*"

**Adding a value**

```
var dictionary = ["A": 1, "B": 2]

if let oldValue = dictionary.updateValue(100, forKey: "C") {
    print("Old value: \(oldValue)")
} else {
    print("New value added")
}
```

It prints: "*New value added*"